# echo not working after ps aux | grep -ie $1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I am creating a simple script to kill all processes containing a specific word.

The code looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

ps aux | grep -ie $1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

echo $(ps aux | grep -ie $1)
```

In the end, I am doing simple verification by printing all processes with a specific word, but when I execute the script (for instance with `./kill.sh tomcat`) I get the following:

```
kill: (3341): No such process
Killed
```

Echo is not working?!

Comment: You are killing yourself. Also `echo $(...)` is a useless use of echo, it's like `echo $(echo $(echo $(echo $(...)))))`.... just execute the thing you want to execute.

Comment: Why not use killall?

Comment: Look for `pgrep` and `pkill` commands in Linux. They are designed for this kind of jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing:

```
./kill.sh tomcat
```

which means in `ps aux` output you will see yourself:

```
# inside sccript
$ ps aux | grep tomcat
...
user     770205  0.0  0.0   9696  2752 pts/4    S+   14:42   0:00 ./kill.sh tomcat
...
```

And then `xargs kill -9` will kill your script.

Do not use `ps aux | grep`. Use `pgrep`.

Remember to quote variable expansions.

Use http://shellcheck.net to check for common script errors.

`echo $(..)` is a useless use of echo. Just execute the thing inside braces.

```
pgrep "$1" | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill -0
pgrep "$1" | xargs --no-run-if-empty ps u
```

Comment: Problem is that `pgrep` is not returning anything for **tomcat** as **tomcat** is just a part of classpath (it would return for **java**, but I don't want to kill all java) so I need `ps aux | grep`.

```
marko    16802  5.5  5.0 10048692 816396 pts/0 Sl   11:13   0:37 /home/marko/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java ... -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /home/marko/servers/phoenix/runtime/host/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/marko/servers/phoenix/runtime/host/bin/ **tomcat** -juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/marko/servers/phoenix/runtime/host
```

Comment: `pgrep -f` is working ! Only I presume that **kill** should go with **-9** and not **-0**

Comment: and as noted in the other answer, use `pkill`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to end process based on a pattern you can use pkill tool, for example, "pkill -e"  will show what task was  ended

*me@CPX-QQ9EFGSXDJ4:~$ pkill -e ping

ping killed (pid 8382)*